# CSS vertical family tree - first-child last-child

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a tree in css flex and it looks correct:

[image]

And here is the code:

```css
.dot {
  width: 50px;
  height:60px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
}
.dot::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 10px;
  height:10px;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 5px);
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-left: solid 10px #900;
}
.dot::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #ddd;
}
.tree {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.tree>:first-child::before {
  height: 80px;
}
.tree>:first-child::after {
  top: 0;
}
.kid {
  display: flex;
}
.kid>div {
  border-top: solid 10px #900;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.kid>:first-child, .kid>:last-child {
  border-top-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.kid>:first-child::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height:10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-top: solid 10px #900;
  border-left: solid 10px #900;
}
.kid>:last-child::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  height:10px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  border-top: solid 10px #900;
  border-right: solid 10px #900;
  margin-left: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
.tree::before {
  /* for tree is the last kid */
  /* margin-left: calc(5px - 50%) !important; */
  /* also need fix if tree is first child */
}
.kid>:only-child::before {
  border-top: 0;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="kid">
  <div class="dot" title="a"></div>
  <div class="tree" title="b">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="kid">
      <div class="dot" title="b1"></div>
      <div class="tree" title="b2">
        <div class="dot"></div>
        <div class="kid">
          <div class="dot"></div>
          <div class="tree">
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="kid">
              <div class="dot"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="tree">
            <div class="dot"></div>
            <div class="kid">
              <div class="dot"></div>
              <div class="dot"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dot"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dot" title="b3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dot" title="c"></div>
</div>
```

When kid's first element is a tree, or the last element is a tree, or it is an only kid as a tree, then it look **not** right as per following (by delete a or c or b1 or b3 or delete both a and b):

[image]

I can fix by remove the following:

```
.tree {
  align-items: center;
}
```

But it affect others.

Anyone can help?

[Also there is a gap for the first element inside a tree, but when background is transparent, I do not care much]

Comment: However I got an answer from google: https://codepen.io/simplyhue/pen/pjEYGo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I have modified from codepen.io/simplyhue/pen/pjEYGo as followings:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tree {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
.tree ul {
  padding-top: 10px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
.tree li {
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
  /*added for long names*/
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0 -2px 0 -2px;
}
/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/
.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
}
.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}
/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  /*display: none;*/
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  left: 0;
}
/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child {
  /*padding-top: 0;*/
}
/*Remove left connector from first child and right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 10px;
}
.tree li a {
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}
.husband {
  float: left;
}
.wife {
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
<li>
  <a href="#">Father</a>--<a href="#">Mother</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">B</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">B1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Child</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">C1</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">C2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">C21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C22</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">C23</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="husband" href="#">C3</a>--<a class="wife">Wife</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Kid</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kid</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">D</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Kid</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Kid</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In case you need it similarly

Comment: You need to replace all `a:hover+ul` with `a:hover~ul` so that the highlights on the lineage could properly take effect when hovering over the father/husband. And in fact, the source code should come from [TheCodePlayer](http://thecodeplayer.com/experiments/css3-family-tree-multiple-parents.html).